# how to close/toggle visibility of the street view in a custom google map API v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i built a custom map using google api v3, and I allow my users to use the streetview feature, but i would be able to close it and go back to the regular map by clicking a button (not he X within th emap but my own button)...what's the command to do that? i cant find it in the docs

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14440868/414385

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this under the pageLoad()

```
$("#streetview_click").appendTo("#map_canvas");

// google streetmap [top bar (north) ]
$("#streetview_click").click(function(){
    var panorama = map.getStreetView();
    if(panorama){panorama.setVisible(false);}
});
```

for more information about streetview script functions check this topic on Google groups:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/d87b18de3a096b8d/b56a04a0440f5016?lnk=gst&q=streetview+close+button#b56a04a0440f5016